# How to visualize decision tree model/object in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, decision-tree, apache-spark-ml

Is there any way to visualize/plot decision tree created using either mllib or ml library in pyspark. Also how to get information like number of records in leaf nodes. Thanks

Comment: Use of python to plot pyspark decision tree is also fine.

Answer (score 3):

First you need to use model.toDebugString to get an output like that on your random forest model :

```
 "RandomForestClassificationModel (uid=rfc_6c4ceb92ba78) with 20 trees
  Tree 0 (weight 1.0):
    If (feature 0 <= 3="" 10="" 1.0)="" if="" (feature="" <="0.0)" predict:="" 0.0="" else=""> 6.0)
       Predict: 0.0
     Else (feature 10 > 0.0)
      If (feature 12 <= 12="" 63.0)="" predict:="" 0.0="" else="" (feature=""> 63.0)
       Predict: 0.0
    Else (feature 0 > 1.0)
     If (feature 13 <= 3="" 1.0)="" if="" (feature="" <="3.0)" predict:="" 0.0="" else=""> 3.0)
       Predict: 1.0
     Else (feature 13 > 1.0)
      If (feature 7 <= 7="" 1.0)="" predict:="" 0.0="" else="" (feature=""> 1.0)
       Predict: 0.0
  Tree 1 (weight 1.0):
    If (feature 2 <= 11="" 15="" 1.0)="" if="" (feature="" <="0.0)" predict:="" 0.0="" else=""> 0.0)
       Predict: 1.0
     Else (feature 15 > 0.0)
      If (feature 11 <= 11="" 0.0)="" predict:="" 0.0="" else="" (feature=""> 0.0)
       Predict: 1.0
    Else (feature 2 > 1.0)
     If (feature 12 <= 5="" 31.0)="" if="" (feature="" <="0.0)" predict:="" 0.0="" else=""> 0.0)
       Predict: 0.0
     Else (feature 12 > 31.0)
      If (feature 3 <= 3="" 4.0)="" predict:="" 0.0="" else="" (feature=""> 4.0)
       Predict: 0.0
  Tree 2 (weight 1.0):
    If (feature 8 <= 4="" 6="" 1.0)="" if="" (feature="" <="2.0)" predict:="" 0.0="" else=""> 10875.0)
       Predict: 1.0
     Else (feature 6 > 2.0)
      If (feature 1 <= 1="" 36.0)="" predict:="" 0.0="" else="" (feature=""> 36.0)
       Predict: 1.0
    Else (feature 8 > 1.0)
     If (feature 5 <= 4="" 0.0)="" if="" (feature="" <="4113.0)" predict:="" 0.0="" else=""> 4113.0)
       Predict: 1.0
     Else (feature 5 > 0.0)
      If (feature 11 <= 11="" 2.0)="" predict:="" 0.0="" else="" (feature=""> 2.0)
       Predict: 0.0
  Tree 3 ...
```

Save it under some .txt file then use : https://github.com/tristaneljed/Decision-Tree-Visualization-Spark

Comment: Do we have something in pyspark only instead of using d3.js. Also model.toDebugString  does not give what % of data is going into each node.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the number of statistics of all the leaf nodes, like impurity, gain, gini, Array of element classified into each label by the model data file.

The data file is located where you save the model/ data/

```
model.save(location)
modeldf = spark.read.parquet(location+"data/*")
```

This file contains much of the needed meta data for the decision tree or even randomForest. You can extract all the needed information like.

```
noderows = modeldf.select("id","prediction","leftChild","rightChild","split").collect()
df = pd.Dataframe([[rw['id'],rw['gain],rw['impurity'],rw['gini']] for rw in noderows if rw['leftChild'] < 0 and rw['rightChild'] < 0])
df.show()
```